# Xamarin Firebase Cloud messages intermittently not working

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using **Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging v3.1.2** (nuget) and intermittently I'm not receiving any notification messages on iPhones.

In my latest test, sending messages from the Firebase console:

1. Message 1: Recieved on **iPhone** and Android
2. Message 2 (Duplicate of
   1): Only recieved on Android
3. Message 3 (Duplicate of 1): Only
   recieved on Android
4. Message 4 (Duplicate of 1): Only recieved on
   Android
5. Message 5 (new message): Only recieved on Android

As this works intermittently, I assume the implementation should be okay? Does anyone know of any issues which might explain this behavior?

```
private void RegisterForPushNotifications() {
    // Register your app for remote notifications.
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0)) {
        // iOS 10 or later
        var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
            //Console.WriteLine(granted);
        });

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
    }
    else {
        // iOS 9 or before
        var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
        var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
    }

    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
}
```

Would be very grateful if someone could help me shed some light on this!

Comment: From where are you sending notificatins?

Comment: @r15 For the test, I was using the Firebase Console to send the messages

Comment: Generate apk in release mode and try. Debug mode isn't that accurate.

Comment: This is release-mode, unfortunately

Comment: How are you collecting  `token ` to send notifications

Comment: @r15 I'm using topics which the user subscribes on a la "Messaging.SharedInstance.Subscribe(topic);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be a bug in Xamarin.iOS.CloudMessaging; when downgrading 3.1.2 -> 2.0.8 everything started working again.

I have posted an issue to the github repo.